# AWS Amplify native app client secret required to proceed but causes exception for having it?

Tags: aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am attempting to import authorization from an existing backend for multiple frontends (in this case both an Android and iOS app; this error is starting from the Android side of things though) however when following the guides out there, I get stopped on this step due to the error:

```
% amplify import auth
Using service: Cognito, provided by: awscloudformation
✔ What type of auth resource do you want to import? · Cognito User Pool only
? Select the User Pool you want to import: …  

❯ The selected Cognito User Pool does not have at least 1 Native app client configured. Native app clients are app clients with a client secret.
dev-user-pool (us-east-1_.........)
```

So I create an App client with an App client secret to continue, only after I get this exception after calling Amplify.Auth.signIn:

```
Sign in failed
    com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unable to verify secret hash for client .......................... (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: ........-....-....-....-............)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:420)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:229)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:6329)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.initiateAuth(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:4290)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$24.run(CognitoUser.java:2949)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.AuthenticationContinuation.continueTask(AuthenticationContinuation.java:147)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6$1.getAuthenticationDetails(AWSMobileClient.java:1224)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.getSession(CognitoUser.java:1032)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1174)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

All the resources I've found around this exception seem to explain to do the opposite but I can't continue as stated if I do not create an App client secret?